# Google Street View Caching

Tags: google-maps, caching, google-street-view

I am working on a project with Google Street View.

We want to make the transitions smoother by caching the pages around our start point and adding to the end point (depending on our heading) as we go.

Has anyone had experience doing that with Street View?

When we create the map and panorama object, it seems to change between initial creation and final loading.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('streetview'), {
    center: vancouver,
    zoom: 18,
    streetViewControl: true
  });


  // We get the map's default panorama and set up some defaults.
  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(vancouver);
  panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 265,
    pitch: 0
  }));
  panorama.setOptions({
    'addressControlOptions': {
    'position': google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    }
  });

  panorama.setVisible(true);
```